# No git inside apache airflow docker container

Tags: git, docker, airflow

I need help regarding `git` inside my latest airflow, I am using this image https://hub.docker.com/layers/apache/airflow/latest/images/sha256-3e0ab13f9525974867cbb612ff632d332b838b05fac4e59bf83f700827744d7d?context=explore and running a container using that but when I am trying to execute this below task I am getting errors

**current snippets**

```
# Create a BashOperator to sync the Git repositories
git_sync_task = BashOperator(
    task_id='git_sync_task',
    bash_command='cd /opt/airflow/service1 && git pull origin main',
    dag=dag,
)
```

**I am getting this error,**

> [2023-01-04, 13:09:30 UTC] {subprocess.py:75} INFO - Running command: ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'cd /opt/***/service1 && git pull origin main']
> [2023-01-04, 13:09:30 UTC] {subprocess.py:86} INFO - Output:
> [2023-01-04, 13:09:30 UTC] {subprocess.py:93} INFO - /bin/bash: line 1: git: command not found [2023-01-04, 13:09:30 UTC]{subprocess.py:97} INFO - Command exited with return code 127
> [2023-01-04, 13:09:30 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1772} ERROR - Task failed with exception

when I am trying to install `git` manually inside `airflow_airflow-webserver_1` container I am also getting permission-related error,

> default@3df7bafd3a37:/opt/airflow$ apt-get install git E: Could not
> open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission
> denied) E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock
> (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?

**How can I fix that git error?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that the `apache/airflow` Docker images run under a non-root user. You can set your Docker image to run as root before installing git to avoid permission issues, but take under consideration security issues etc

```
USER root
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install git
...
...
# change back to base image user
USER 50000
```

Comment: thanks for posting that, I have solved it and added an answer. Thanks again....

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did finally to build a custom image because `git` is not present inside the latest apache airflow image. Another point to note here is we need the `root` permission and `airflow` permission to install some services. So this finally works for me-

```
FROM apache/airflow:latest
USER root           <----------------------- see here
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    vim git curl unzip groff less \
    && apt-get autoremove -yqq --purge \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
# AWS CLI installation
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip && ./aws/install

USER airflow      <----------------------- see here
# Required package installation
RUN pip install --user --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --user -r /requirements.txt

# Install Poetry
RUN pip install poetry
```